# Sencha Touch > tabPanel > set activeItem

Tags: extjs

Here's my code.i want set tab 2(xtype: 'index_xx') as my default tab,and i user 'activeItem: 1 ' but it not works,tks help

```
Ext.define('Sencha.view.PadMain', {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
xtype: 'padmain_xx',
requires: [
    'Sencha.view.Index',
    'Sencha.view.Article'
],
config: {
    tabBar: {
        docked: 'left',
        cls:'pad_menu',
        activeItem: 1 , //<--------------
        scrollable: {
            direction: 'vertical',
            indicators: false
        },
        width:200
    },

    items: [
        { title: '&nbsp;',cls:'top_bar'},
        { xtype: 'index_xx'},
        { xtype: 'article_xx'}
    ]
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I think activeTab is a property of tab panel. You can try this code if it helps:

```
      Ext.define('Sencha.view.PadMain', {
          extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
          activeTab: 1,
```